# Strict firewall & proxy, no stratum+tcp connectivity; what are my options?

Tags: miner-configuration, stratum, proxy

I have access to a system for mining behind a squid proxy. No external connectivity except for HTTP & HTTPS. The access on my mining system is also fairly restrictive, but I have managed to build and compile `*minerd` for it.

> **System specs:**
>
> CentOS 6.5 x86_64, dual quadcore xeon, 16GB ram

This is for a project a group of us are working on; we are mining a private blockchain, not part of any *coin group (ours is based on DOGEcoin, I believe, but private).

The server *only* allows stratum+tcp to serverIP:3333. my minerd can't reach it due to the HTTP/HTTPS only outbound restriction.

I have looked at the Stratum Miner Proxy, but I have difficulty getting python to download what it requires to config and make/setup the proxy, when I run the `setup.py`

Is Stratum Miner Proxy still my best bet, or should I look into setting up a shell/relay outside the network that accepts HTTP from my miner and sends/receives stratum+tcp to the server? any other suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Are you mining your own coin or a publicly available coin?

Comment: We are mining our own coin. We intend to use them at an event later this year, when it will be open to the public for participation in the event. No exchange will be set up; if people wish to sell or buy these coins they may (we sure can't stop them), but there will be no official sponsorship or exchange structure. The coins will be used as currency at the event for intangible benefits (early access to something, better seating, etc.)